# How to initialise a class variable?

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

I know that for an instance variable all I have to do is put it inside the initialise method in the instance side and assign it a default value. But how I do this for class variable ? I tried to create an initialise method at class side but it did not give my variable a default value so I had to do this in one of my methods

```
pythonString ifNil:[pythonString := '']
```

But I don't like this approach.

I also found this for squeak , http://forum.world.st/Howto-initialize-class-variables-td1667813.html again I don't like this approach either. Is there a proper way of doing this. In Python it was fairly simple case of assignment why is it so cryptic for Pharo ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all I hope that you are talking about instance variable of a class object (not a thing that you define on instance side as "class variable").

`initialize` is working, but it's being run upon instance creation. And instance (a class object) exists already when you define `initialize` method.

So when you define your class for the first time, you should run it by yourself e.g. `YourClass initialize`, bun later each time you load your class into system it should be initialised.

Comment: No I mean class variable defined at instance side

Comment: Answer of Uko hold both for class variables and instance variables of classes. You should write your initialization on the class-side #initialize method and execute manually the first time. Monticello will take care of executing it when it loads your code in the future.

Comment: thank you both Damien and Uko, answer accepted and upvoted :)

Comment: Am I expected to invoke `super initialize` from my initializer? Note I mean `super initialize` and not `superclass initialize` which would obviously do the wrong thing.